# Do pending transaction orders on the Ardor coin exchange or Ardor asset exchange expire?

Tags: transactions, ardor, ardor-asset-exchange

I made a transaction on the coin exchange and if I never cancel it, when would it expire and return the funds to me? Or do I have to submit a new **cancel order**? And is this the same for asset exchange orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order remains active until you cancel it by issuing a Cancel Order transaction.  Which means you will pay a transaction fee but you will get the unused portion of your funds returned to you.